# How to add an header file in a C project on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, linker

I real need help over here, I have to do this ASCIITwitter project for an university's exam and I'm stucked with this problem:

I have to add a header file and a source file on my project of course, so first I tried some easy code to see if I'm capable to do this.
Just a program to do some square operations:

There's my code:
Twitter.h

```
#ifndef TWITTER_H_
#define TWITTER_H_
int square(int);
#endif /* TWITTER_H_ */
```

Twitter.c

```
#include "Twitter.h"

int square(int x)
{
return x*x;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Twitter.h"
int main(void)
{
int y;
y=square(5);
printf("%d\n",y);
system("PAUSE");
}
```

But it give to me "undefined reference to 'square' and I really don't know how to fix this. I've tried searching on internet, but I'm working on windows, I don't have any makefile, I just want to make this work. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have both *C* files in the project? Is it CDT managed project or Makefile project?

Comment: Make sure that the files are in the same directory. Otherwise, It will not be able to find the reference.

Comment: I'm on MinGW, I've just clicked on "new c project, executable, MinGW".
The files (header and source) are in the same folders and project. I really don't know what's happening over here

Comment: That's not a problem of the C language, nor compilation or the header.